# Query SharePoint search to get all tasks from a list with specific name where creator is A or B

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have > 500 SiteCollections based on the same Template. Each SiteCollection has always a List called "MyTasks". I think it is not a good idea to do a crosssite query on all the lists due to performance.

Is it possible to use SharePoint 2013 search to query

- all SiteCollection under http://domain/managedpath1
- for List with Name = "MyTasks"
- to retrieve all tasks created by UserA or UserB or UserC (not a single user)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it

You can do this with a KeyworkQuery. In the KeyworkQuery.QueryText yu need to use

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "contentclass:\"STS_ListItem_Task\" AND "path:\"http://sp2013/sites/sitename\" AND "AssignedTo:\"Name Lastname\""
```

The Listname is not part of the search and therefore i had to use the contenttype or contentclass is my example.